# Make Vertical Resizing Fixed

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I was wondering how I could make my page fixed when minimizing the height of the browser. As of now, height is responsive and everything gets crumpled up. If you resize StackOverflow, height stays static and isn't responsive and that is what I'm going for. I added a fiddle with a basic form.

https://jsfiddle.net/sto3d7e4/

HTML:

```
<div class="contactform">
 <div class="bg">
  <h1><img src="https://i.imgur.com/F8fAFJH.png" alt="">Contact Form</h1>
   <form action=""
  method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Program of Interest" name="Program">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Gender" name="gender">
    <textarea placeholder="Questions/Concerns"></textarea>
    <input id="button" type="submit" value="Send">
   </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contactform {
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background: #eee;
}

.contactform input {
display: block;
margin: 10px 0px;
height: 50px;
width: 400px;
background: transparent;
border: 0.1px solid;
outline-color: #eee;
color: #eee;
}

input::placeholder {
color: #eee;
padding: 0px 10px
}

.bg {
width: 80vw;
height: 80vh;
background: #89c4f4;
position: relative;
position: fixed;
}

.bg  {
position: relative;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.bg h1 {
margin: 0;
color: #eee;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
display: flex;
}

.bg img {
height: 40px;
margin-right: 15px;
}

.bg textarea {
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
/max-width: 250px;
max-height: 200px;
background: transparent;
border: 0.1px solid #eee;
color: #eee;
outline-color: #eee;
}

textarea::placeholder {
color: #eee;
padding: 0px 10px
}

#button {
background:;
color: #eee;
border: 0.1px solid #eee;
transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
}

#button:hover {
background: #eee;
color: #89c4f4;
}
```

Comment: You use `vh` for `height`, that is relative to the viewport's (window's) height...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto yea that solves it. However I would still like to make the height 100% of the viewport. Is there any way?

Comment: Try `min-height: 100vh;`...

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:block`

```css
.menu_item{
    height: 15%;
    width: 45%;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu_icon{
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
.menu_item a {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_item">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <img class="menu_icon" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/gweb-uniblog-publish-prod/static/blog/images/google-200x200.7714256da16f.png" alt="Templates"/>
        <span>Templates</span>
    </a>
</div>
```